# How to grid objects on a canvas in Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, chess

I am currently working on creating a chess game in python using the class Tkinter. I am making the chessboard right now. Here is some example code of what I am doing:

```
board_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, borderwidth=1)
board_canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew', columnspan=8, rowspan=8)

x = 100
y = 100

a1 = board_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, x, y, fill='black')
a2 = board_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, x, y, fill='white')
a3 = board_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, x, y, fill='black')
```

My question is how to grid my canvas objects so that they don't all just sit on top of each other. Or if that doesn't work, what is a better way that I can layout my chessboard?

Comment: Have you tried simply giving them different coordinates? It's just very basic math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each rectangle has four coordinates(x0, y0, x1, y1: (x0, y0) is the top left corner, and (x1, y1) is the pixel outside the bottom right corner. So you just need to increment the x coordinate for the top left and bottom right for each square.

```
import tkinter
mainWindow =tkinter.Tk()

board_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, borderwidth=1)
board_canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew', columnspan=8, rowspan=8)

x = 100
y = 100

a1 = board_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, x, y, fill='black')
a2 = board_canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, y, fill='white')
a3 = board_canvas.create_rectangle(200, 0, 300, y, fill='black')

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Of course, for an entire chessboard, you would probably want to increment the values using a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I shoulda thought to set the coordinates differently instead of trying to use .grid. Thanks!